# Original wavelets articles.

Tags: reference-request, wavelets

I have spent most of the last two hours searching for the two original articles

- The article by Y. Meyer, where he constructs his smooth orthonormal wavelet basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
- The article by P. G. Lemarié-Rieusset, where he presents what will become known as the Battle-Lemarié wavelets.

I am aware that these articles probably is in French.

Are there any good detectives that might help?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Seems he won the Abel price this year, how could I have missed that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the first article.
  Here's [an early article by Lemarié and Meyer](http://dmle.icmat.es/pdf/MATEMATICAIBEROAMERICANA_1986_02_01-02_02.pdf), but there must be something even earlier.  One sees references to

- Y. Meyer, *La Transformation en Ondelettes et les Nouveaux Paraproduits*, Actes du Colloque d'Analyse Nonlineaire du CEREMADE, Univ. Paris — Dauphine,

but I find no trace of the actual paper.  There are also [this](http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/45-1/1.pdf), [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252340981_Painless_Nonorthogonal_Expansions), and [this](http://archive.numdam.org/article/SEDP_1986-1987____A5_0.pdf).

The second article you ask about may be

- P.G. Lemarié-Rieusset. *Ondelettes à
  Localisation Exponentielle*. J. Math. Pures Appl., **67** (1988), pp. 227–236.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be online.

Answer (score 1):

The wavelet described in the [wikipedia article on Meyer wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meyer_wavelet#cite_note-1) seems to be in his book **Ondelettes et operateurs** from 1990, which must be several years later than his first papers where he built it, but in that book it is reasonable that you will find a citation to the paper (and usually also a more easily digested format in books than in technical papers).

---

There seems to be an english translation "Wavelets and operators":

Meyer, Yves Wavelets and operators. Translated from the 1990 French original by D. H. Salinger. Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 37. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1992. xvi+224 pp. ISBN: 0-521-42000-8; 0-521-45869-2